# how to change from zfs to ext4

Tags: linux, ext4, zfs, lxd

i accidentally create zfs pool to sda1 with

```
sudo zpool create -f lxd-zfs-pool /dev/sda1
```

zpool status output is

```
pool: lxd-zfs-pool
state: ONLINE
scan: none requested
config:

NAME          STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
lxd-zfs-pool  ONLINE       0     0     0
  sda1        ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

sda1 has ext4 file system before create zfs pool.

How can i get back all data in sda1 ?

Comment: Try using [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)

Comment: Do you want to know how you can create a new ext4 file system no the partition or is your question about the reconstruction of the actual data?